# Find and replace specific characters in Word headings

Tags: replace, ms-word

I have a huge size word document (32MB). All I want to do is to find and replace the following characters with something (say space or nothing, that is remove them) but only in all the headings (h1 to h9 or every heading level being used) and not anywhere else:
,-_;~%&*()?/.

Can anyone help? I want to do it using a macro. I know the manual way using the Find dialog but it is too cumbersome because of the huge size of the document. Thank you for help.